# Unable to get the data from a webpage

Tags: c#, asp.net, jsp, model-view-controller

I am trying to **scrape** some data from a webpage. I have a sample code which does this job in most of the website but throwing error only when i use the following urls as input. Am I missing something here?

URLs where I'm facing issue:
https://www1.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/option_chain/optionKeys.jsp
https://www.nseindia.com/get-quotes/derivatives?symbol=NIFTY&identifier=OPTIDXNIFTY28-05-2020PE9000.00

Code:
string result = null;
string url = "https://www.nseindia.com/get-quotes/derivatives?symbol=NIFTY&identifier=OPTIDXNIFTY28-05-2020PE9000.00";
WebResponse response = null;
StreamReader reader = null;

```
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.Method = "GET";
            response = request.GetResponse();
            reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8);
            result = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // handle error
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: for start remove the `MessageBox.Show` - this is not working on asp.net, its for desktop programming

Comment: what is the exception?

Comment: seems like server not answering you are you authorize? is server using "POST" method

Comment: No, it is a Get method, i have verified it. Any help will be really great.

Comment: try using selenium web driver